# ATTACH DATABASE on a Different Drive with spatialite/python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, spatialite

I am new to both GIS and python, so thanks for your patience with me.
I need to copy data from one database to another.  The tables are identical and I plan to simply clear the destination table (DELETE FROM) and load it with data from the source database (INSERT * INTO [destination] FROM [source];) My challenge is that the source and destination tables are on different drives.

I am using the following code:

```
# Connect to the origin database.
ns_db_pnm = 'C:\\temp\\db_name.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(ns_db_pnm)

# Load the SpatiaLite extension to SQLite.
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.execute("select load_extension('mod_spatialite', 'sqlite3_modspatialite_init')")

cur = conn.cursor()
# Attach the destination database FROM A DIFFERENT DRIVE
d_db_pnm = 'D:\\db_path\\db_name.db'
cur.execute('ATTACH DATABASE ' + d_db_pnm + ' AS delivery;')
```

The code fails on the execute with the following error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

It appears to really not like the fact that my attached database is on a different drive.

All the examples I see use a relative path (no drive name) to the database.  Apparently I will need to change a working directory or some such. Please advise on how I might make this happen. My appeals to the all-knowing Google have not produced a viable answer.

Comment: Do you need the new db to be linked to the old db in a dynamic way? or just copy over data once? Also you probably don't need `;` at the end of the query there

Comment: I only need to copy data once.  Two databases in two locations that must be synced. The ` ; ` is a habit. After the ATTACH statement, I want to run a series of queries such as:

Comment: Took too long...
I only need to copy data once.  Two databases in two locations that must be synced. The ` ; ` is a habit. After the ATTACH statement, I want to run a series of queries such as:
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM delivery.dest_table")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO delivery.dest_table SELECT * FROM main.source_table")

Comment: I don't think you need to do the `attach` deal. You should be able to just select everything from the source table, and insert into the new db. That seems easier to me

Comment: @SuperStew, that sounds like exactly what I'd like to do.  A simple "INSERT INTO db_dest.destination_table (SELECT * FROM db_source.source_table)" would be wonderful, but that means the cursor object needs to have access to both databases.  How do I get that to happen is my original question.  If the ATTACH is not the correct answer, please enlighten me - I'm pretty much in the dark!

Comment: It may be technically possible to do it that way, but i was thinking just query the data from one, leave it as a list or whatever in memory, and then insert it into the other db with another connection/cursor entirely. If the data is very large, you could write to a csv file instead of keeping it all in memory.

Comment: Don't know Python, but I _think_ the problem is you're not making the path into an SQLite string... you probably need something like `cur.execute('ATTACH DATABASE \'' + d_db_pnm + '\' AS delivery;')` -- note the `\'` either side of the filename.

Comment: @SuperStew, the code I already wrote does exactly as you explained.  I was hoping for a straight table-to-table query which would be significantly faster.  I'm dealing with potentially large data and a line-by-line read/write can be tedious even with transactions.  TripeHound - Thanks for the suggestion.  When time allows (I've had to move on) I will definitely see if your solution will work for me.